# What does JQuery Mobile add to a div when you call .changePage() on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I was using changePage() to switch between divs (pages) in my body.
I don't want to use changePage anymore, just jquery show/hide.

But if I don't call changePage, the div I show loses it's jqm style.

The footer isn't fixed anymore, it is at the bottom of the page.

The div height isn't the viewport's height anymore, it has become the content's height.

There was a padding-top so that the header doesn't go over the content, it isn't there anymore.

I've tried adding data-role:page and ui-page-active manually on show but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds `page-active` class and removes the class from any other page divs. You can manually trigger page styling using trigger('create') on the page div to add styles.

Comment: Yes, it does add those classes, but manually it doesn't work. By using .trigger("create") it does. I was already triggering it on my new div but before inserting it in the DOM. By triggering it after the append, it does work.